# Is there a way to recreate an RSA CRT Key in Java without knowing all 8 parameters?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I have an implementation that needs to store the components of an RSA key pair on different hosts. The components are stored in a single encrypted vault with a number of other parameters, so just using pem files is not an option. I would prefer to store the private key in the CRT form using the quintuple. For no good reason, the RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec class requires all eight components when only the quintuple is necessary to recreate the key. Am I stuck with the modulus/private exponent form, or will the implementation rebuild a CRT key for me? I've been digging around on Google all day without much success.

Comment: Rather than digging around on google all day why not just try a simple experiment and see what happens?

Comment: Which values do you have? In general it is possible to (re-)generate the CRT parameters even if you just have the modulus and private exponent (and can guess the public exponent). I don't think Java will do this for you though.

Comment: I have the quintuple. The p prime, the q prime, the prime p exponent, the prime q exponent, and the CRT coefficient. I don't want to store the modulus or either exponent, but I especially don't want to store the public exponent. @JamesKPolk, I tried it. It threw a null pointer exception.